# Conditional probability and the normal distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

$$X \sim N(50, σ^2) $$

$$P(Y < 90 | Y >15) = \frac{P(X > 90)}{P(X < 15)}.$$

Is this line correct?

Many thanks.

Comment: What's $Y$?  If you meant $Y=X$, then no, it doesn't look at all correct.

Comment: Note that $P(B|A) = \frac{P(A ~\mbox{and}~ B)}{P(A)}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Bayes formula, provided that $P(Y<15)\neq 0$ (but that's impoossible, since $Y \tilde{} N(50,\sigma^2) $), you have that 
$$ P(A\mid B)=\frac{P(B\mid A)\,P(A)}{P(B)} $$
hence you have
$$ P(Y<90\mid Y>15)=\frac{P( Y>15\mid Y<90)\,P(Y<90)}{P(Y>15)} $$
and hence using [Condition Probability Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability) you have:
$$ P(Y<90\mid Y>15)=\frac{P(15<Y<90)}{P(Y>15)} $$
and you can easily manage the fraction looking at the tables, i.e., noticing that $P(15<Y<90)= F(90)-F(15)$ and $P(Y>15)=1-P(Y<15)=1-F(15)$ where I defined $F$ as the cumulative distribution function of the process $Y$
        $$ F_Y(y)=P(Y\leq y)$$

Comment: Why not use conditional probability formula on $P(Y<90\mid Y>15)$ directly, instead of translating it in terms of $P(Y>15\mid Y<90)$ and then applying conditional probability formula to $P(Y>15\mid Y<90)$ (and watch simplifications occur, naturally...)?

Comment: Ya, actually I noticed it after I posted the answer... Sorry if I was prolix

Comment: "No you're **WRONG**!"

Comment: I see my error, I am a fool! Thank you taking the time to answer my trite question and no need to apologise for being prolix, a touch of tautology is good once in a while!